# How does Pandas store timezone information?

Tags: python, pandas

Timestamp columns are stored internally in UTC, regardless of whether they have a timezone or not. This is stated in the docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones

So how is timezone information stored internally? There must be some sort of "tag" which makes that column contain pd.Timestamp entries with tz="America/New_York" or whatever the timezone is.

Context:
I am writing data to disk in a way that is not specific to Python, e.g I am not using `pickle`. When I retrieve the data I want the timezone information to remain.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what Pandas uses to store timezone internally, but possibly something like `datetime.tzinfo`.

On how to represent timezone info cross-platform, the most straight-forward way I can think of is to write the timestamp out as string, using particular format code for the timezone, e.g. `%z` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). When another system reads the string, it can parse the timestamp+timezone into the system's own representation.